# How to get "+" form an URL using GET method in PHP?

Tags: php, get

**From the below URL**

> http://nis.com/projects/cc_intranet/mauth/lib_test/?authenticate=7JaoTs9NM4xdTnZpQE+q73X4N0oqMvX+BSlLrsqDeUL6VwaXt/91ZYOviomSIt/DvPuEjKAvip5++++++++++UZuVQWJ53mQa83Dz5EX4sfbjI1iXQjHrdwa2Ecca1bLe6MHis9UuSs

When i use "$_GET['authenticate'];" and then print it,
i get the the following output where "+" doesn't display.

> 7JaoTs9NM4xdTnZpQE q73X4N0oqMvX
>   BSlLrsqDeUL6VwaXt/91ZYOviomSIt/DvPuEjKAvip5
>   UZuVQWJ53mQa83Dz5EX4sfbjI1iXQjHrdwa2Ecca1bLe6MHis9UuSs

Is there any way how to get the exact same result ?? (i.e) in my case the "+" symbol has not been passed to the $_GET['authenticate'] while printing it ???

Comment: i found a solution by passing "urlencode($authenticate)" and then when i print $_GET['authenticate'] i get the exact result... can anyone say whether this solution is safe and there wont be any problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is reserved character in `GET` queries to represent a space character. If you really need `+` character in your query you need to replace it with `%2B`:

`authenticate=7JaoTs9NM4xdTnZpQE%2Bq73X4N0oqMvX%2BBSlLrsqDeUL6VwaXt/91ZYOviomSIt/DvPuEjKAvip5%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2BUZuVQWJ53mQa83Dz5EX4sfbjI1iXQjHrdwa2Ecca1bLe6MHis9UuSs`

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) php function is a good way to create a proper URL with all reserved symbols escaped.

[urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php) function is for decoding such URLs.